# Docker for Windows Windows: Keep linux container running after logout

Tags: linux, docker, windows-server-2016, docker-compose

I've installed Docker for Windows on Windows Server 2016 using Hyper-V as Hypervisor for linux containers. The docker service starts automatically when I login to my account.
I start my docker configuration using docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Everything is working perfectly fine as long as my user is logged in. The docker application offers a web interface that I can access from a workstation. As soon as I log out of my Windows account on the server, the containers stop working. I cannot access the web interface any more.
I tried launching the `docker-compose` command as a service, but this doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a way to start docker-compose user-independant so that it starts automatically after the system booted?